# Custom Field Menu Linking To Custom Field Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm having a hard time linking a menu built with custom fields to a page built the same way.  I'm sure the problem is making it link via permalink, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Employees', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) ); ?> 
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php the_field('title'); ?>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is on http://www.consociate.com/about/meet-the-team/, I want the links on the right to go to a template filled with custom fields (their bio information).  Is this possible?

Thanks so much!  I love this community!

Comment: n whats the problem ? not working is not so descriptive

Comment: If you click on any of the links on the right side of the page, it takes it to an actual page, not a template with the generated custom fields on it.  I guess I'm wanting to pass information through the link and I don't know if that's possible.  So if someone, for example, click on Julia Danbury, I want it to take you to a page filled with her biography information that's generated by custom fields without having to create a page for every employee.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be achived by respecting the wordpress [template hierarchy rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you shouldn't hardcode links or hardcode add parameters to the links, simply use [`<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) then create the resonse php file that will display the info as you want.

Comment: I read through what you linked but am still running into some problems.  Again, I think it's in the way I'm trying to link out to the bio page in http://www.consociate.com/about/meet-the-team/.  I created a php page and now it's simply appending whatever is on that page to the link itself instead of linking me to an actual template that I can pull content into.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but here is my code for that page:

`<div style="float:right;width:33%;">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Employees', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) ); ?> 
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php the_field('title'); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>`